Relational-join Excel tables
I have an excel file and I am trying to find matching values based on these criteria.

For ARMADAS B2: D542295890, I am getting the ARMADAW A2:B05KAYIP
I will look for B05KAYIP in the E column ARMADAIWC and get the
corresponding D SAPIWC value 0010
Then I look for 0010 in column G SAPW and get the matching value of
D542295890 ARMADAS B2.
If B and H match then I want to color them.


This console application finds the matching values but since there are approx. 400K rows of data for both B and H to match it takes ages to finish. I wonder how I can optimize this code to get the matching results like in my code way faster?
using OfficeOpenXml;
using OfficeOpenXml.Style;
using System.Drawing;

string filePath = @"C:\Users\197199\Desktop\SAP-Armada\Test.xlsx";
string logFilePath = @"C:\Users\197199\Desktop\SAP-Armada\matches.txt";

// Ensure the file exists
if (!File.Exists(filePath))
{
    Console.WriteLine("File not found.");
    return;
}
ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;

// Load the Excel file
using var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(filePath));
// Get the first worksheet in the workbook
var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];

// Define column indices (assuming 1-based index)
int armadasCol = 2; // Replace with actual column index for ARMADAS
int armadawCol = 1; // Replace with actual column index for ARMADAW
int armadaiWCCol = 5; // Replace with actual column index for ARMADAIWC
int sapiWCCol = 4; // Replace with actual column index for SAPIWC
int gCol = 7; // Replace with actual column index for G
int sapsCol = 8; // Replace with actual column index for SAPS

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(logFilePath))
{
    // Read the content of the worksheet and perform the comparison
    for (int row = 2; row <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; row++) // Assuming first row is header
    {
        string armadasValue = worksheet.Cells[row, armadasCol].Text;
        string armadawValue = worksheet.Cells[row, armadawCol].Text;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(armadasValue) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(armadawValue))
        {
            continue; // Skip empty rows
        }

        // Find the corresponding value in ARMADAIWC and SAPIWC
        string sapiWCValue = null;
        for (int i = 2; i <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; i++)
        {
            if (worksheet.Cells[i, armadaiWCCol].Text == armadawValue)
            {
                sapiWCValue = worksheet.Cells[i, sapiWCCol].Text;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sapiWCValue))
        {
            continue; // Skip if no corresponding SAPIWC value is found
        }

        // Find the corresponding value in SAPS
        string sapsValue = null;
        for (int j = 2; j <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; j++)
        {
            if (worksheet.Cells[j, gCol].Text == sapiWCValue)
            {
                if (armadasValue == worksheet.Cells[j, sapsCol].Text)
                {
                    sapsValue = worksheet.Cells[j, sapsCol].Text;

                    // Apply coloring to the matching cells
                    worksheet.Cells[row, armadasCol].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                    worksheet.Cells[row, armadasCol].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Yellow);

                    worksheet.Cells[j, sapsCol].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                    worksheet.Cells[j, sapsCol].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Yellow);

                    string message = $"Match found at row {row}: ARMADA WAREHOUSE = {armadawValue}, ARMADA SERIAL = {armadasValue}, SAP WAREHOUSE = {sapiWCValue}, SAP SERIAL = {sapsValue}{Environment.NewLine}";
                    Console.WriteLine(message);
                    writer.WriteLine(message);

                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sapsValue))
        {
            continue; // Skip if no corresponding SAPS value is found
        }
    }
}

// Save the changes
package.Save();

Console.WriteLine("Comparison and coloring completed.");


I changed the title so that it describes what the code does per site goals: "State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it.". Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have.

The problem is that the time complexity of your code is O(N²). This is bad to deal with 400k rows the better solution, as @J_H suggests, is to put your data in a RDBMS and use SQL to query your data.
If you want to do it by code, first build lookup dictionaries and then use these dictionaries to quickly look up values:
// Define column indices (assuming 1-based index)
int armadasCol = 2; // Replace with actual column index for ARMADAS
int armadawCol = 1; // Replace with actual column index for ARMADAW
int armadaiWCCol = 5; // Replace with actual column index for ARMADAIWC
int sapiWCCol = 4; // Replace with actual column index for SAPIWC
int gCol = 7; // Replace with actual column index for G
int sapsCol = 8; // Replace with actual column index for SAPS

using StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(logFilePath) ;

Dictionary<string, (string Armadaw, int Row)> Armadas_Armadaw_mapping = new();
Dictionary<string,(string Sapiwc, int Row)> ARMADAIWC_SAPIWC_mapping = new();
Dictionary<string, (string Saps,int Row)> SAPW_SAPS_mapping = new();
// Read the content of the worksheet and populate dictionaries.
for (int row = 2; row <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; row++) // Assuming first row is header
{
    string armadasValue = worksheet.Cells[row, armadasCol].Text;
    string armadawValue = worksheet.Cells[row, armadawCol].Text;

    Armadas_Armadaw_mapping[armadasValue] = (armadawValue,row);
    // ARMADAIWC and SAPIWC
    string sapiWCValue = worksheet.Cells[row, sapiWCCol].Text;
    string armadaiWCValue = worksheet.Cells[row, armadaiWCCol].Text;
    
    ARMADAIWC_SAPIWC_mapping[armadaiWCValue] = (sapiWCValue,row);
     

    // SAPS
    string sapsValue = worksheet.Cells[row, sapsCol].Text;
    string sapwValue = worksheet.Cells[row, gCol].Text;

    SAPW_SAPS_mapping[sapwValue] = (sapsValue, row); 
}

// search for matching 
foreach(var Armadas_Armadaw in Armadas_Armadaw_mapping)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Armadas_Armadaw.Key) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Armadas_Armadaw.Value.Armadaw))
        continue;

    if (!ARMADAIWC_SAPIWC_mapping.TryGetValue(Armadas_Armadaw.Value.Armadaw,out var SAPIWC))
        continue;
     

    if (!SAPW_SAPS_mapping.TryGetValue(SAPIWC.Sapiwc, out var SAPS))
        continue;

    // Apply coloring to the matching cells
    worksheet.Cells[Armadas_Armadaw.Value.Row, armadasCol].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
    worksheet.Cells[Armadas_Armadaw.Value.Row, armadasCol].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Yellow);

    worksheet.Cells[SAPS.Row, sapsCol].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
    worksheet.Cells[SAPS.Row, sapsCol].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Yellow);

    string message = $"Match found at row {Armadas_Armadaw.Value.Row}: ARMADA WAREHOUSE = {Armadas_Armadaw.Value.Armadaw}, ARMADA SERIAL = {Armadas_Armadaw.Key}, SAP WAREHOUSE = {SAPIWC.Sapiwc}, SAP SERIAL = {SAPS.Saps}{Environment.NewLine}";
    Console.WriteLine(message);
    writer.WriteLine(message);

}
 
// Save the changes
package.Save();

Note: I didn't run the above code and I don't completely sure if it will work or not, but I just show you the idea.

I will try and let you know, thank you.

You described a linear search algorithm which scales with O(N),
where N is more than 400,000 rows.

how I can optimize ... to get the matching results like in my code way faster?

Use an appropriate tool for the task at hand.
Put those rows in an RDBMS already.
Then you can exploit a column index which takes you right to the proper rows,
with O(log N) cost.
You can run a DB report which feeds "color this cell Yellow"
instructions into Excel.
If you insist on keeping those rows in a spreadsheet,
at least sort on the column of interest,
and then binary search on it.

"dump to a DB" - plus good. We had impressive improvements converting  C# using Data libraries to SQL.  Most eye-watering was a several hour process got down to 12 seconds. I wonder if the  internal data/record structure is the main culprit. COBOL is a wickedl-blazing-fast record processor. A record is just a pre-defined number of characters.  24 years ago our desktop pc  COBOL system was processing 500,000 records in about 15 seconds.

Others have said that you need to move the data into a "real" database. Given that you're inside a spreadsheet, that's not actually true, since you can use the facilities of the spreadsheet itself to achieve the same effect, albeit with not quite as much speed-up.
First, if the data sources are not sorted, you make two new sheets within the document, to contain the sorted ranges you want to join. (Use an array SORT function to achieve this.) What you do next depends on whether there will be multiple results per key.
In the simple singular case, you can simply add more columns to one of the new sheets, with lookups into the other sheet. You can pretty much just read out the results from that sheet.
In the complex case, you'd need your script, but instead of the inner loop iterating over the entire second page, you could instead call the built-in search function, or failing that, write your own binary search. Either way, this will reduce the time complexity from O(N²) to O(N×log(N)).
If one sheet is much larger than the other, add the extra columns to the smaller sheet.
